# sql duplicate field

Tags: sql

Here is my table.

```
ProductID    Title                 UPC     Display
43           Motobecane Fantom     2634    0
14           Gravity FSX           3301    1
19           Gravity FSX 1.0       3301    1
56           Mango Macaw           2834    1
```

I want to select rows with duplicate UPC where Display=1. Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
Select ProductID, Title, UPC, Display from Products
Where Display=1
group by UPC having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution assumes SQL Server:

```
SELECT    ProductID,
          Title,
          UPC,
          Display
FROM      Products
WHERE     UPC IN(
                     SELECT   UPC
                     FROM     Products
                     WHERE    DISPLAY = 1
                     GROUP BY UPC
                     HAVING   COUNT(UPC) > 1
                )
AND       Display = 1
```